# SqlCommand back up Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an c# winforms application (.net 2 framework).
I need to backup data bases from my application.
I am trying to do this by executing an SqlCommand asynchronously.
The code is executed with no exceptions but I dont get the .bak file in my destination...

this is the code :

```
#region backup DB using T-SQL command

string connString = "Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("localhost_SQLEXPRESS") + ";Initial Catalog=" + db + ";UserID=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("user") + ";Password=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE " + db + " TO DISK=" + location + "\\" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DataBaseBackupsFolderName") + "\\" + db + ".bak'", sqlConnection1))
    {    
        sqlConnection1.Open();    
        IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the sqlConnection1.Open() and check the value of cmd.CommandText (in particular the filename path)

Comment: Just to make sure... The backup is stored on the server, not on the computer that issued the command (except if both are the same machine).

Comment: The backup is on the computer...

Comment: @Steve This is the command  - 
BACKUP DATABASE DB_Tags_TestingTagBurner TO DISK=D:\New folder\DataBaseBackups\DB_Tags_TestingTagBurner.bak'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL backup line you seem to be missing a single quote at the beginning of the path to the backup file.

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE " + db + " TO DISK='" + location + "\\" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DataBaseBackupsFolderName") + "\\" +db + ".bak'", sqlConnection1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`EndExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery) on your SqlCommand instance in order to throw any eventual exception and thus understand what is wrong with your SQL statements:

```
IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

// Wait for the command to complete

result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

// End the execution and throw any eventual exception

cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
```

As you can see, I have also replaced your original Thread.Sleep() cycle block with a more effective wait on the wait handle of the command.

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx):

> For each call to BeginOperationName, the application should also call
>   EndOperationName to get the results of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Two advices to try to isolate the problem:

1) Get the resulting string (the one you are executing on the SqlCommand and run it manually on SQL Server to make sure the backup commnad is correct.

2) Try a synchronous command with a regular ExecuteNonQuery to see if you are getting a SQL Server exception